# Nginx - remove trailing slash with certain URL categories

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am using nginx 1.14.0 on Ubuntu.

I want to remove trailing slash with every URL's coming after `https://www.example.com/en/authors/*` or `https://www.example.com/de/bloggers/*`

So anyone goes to `https://www.example.com/en/authors/hello/` should be redirected to `https://www.example.com/en/authors/hello` or `https://www.example.com/de/bloggers/hello/` to `https://www.example.com/de/bloggers/hello` and likewise...

I tried some patterns based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293534/regex-nginx-remove-trailing-slashes-not-apply-to-2-folders) answer but seems like it does not fit in my situation since I want all trailing slash removed from only after `/en/authors/*` or `/de/bloggers/*` and it may involve wildcard as well

One of the patterns I tried is `rewrite ^/(?!authors|bloggers)(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;` but it did not work

Comment: In general, that slash is not normally a problem.  Not saying it isn’t one for you, but it would help if you help us understand what problem you are trying to solve, along with this question.

Comment: @Dennis I simply need to remove trailing slash only after https://www.example.com/en/authors/ or https://www.example.com/de/bloggers/

Comment: Sorry, last try:  There must be some reason you want to remove that slash, since it is not normally a problem.  Also, you mention you want to remove the slash, but you also mention that the user would be redirected.  That is a completely different question, so please elaborate what _issue_ you are trying to resolve, rather than the _method_ you hope will accomplish it.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for asking, let me try to explain again. This is custom Django based application which is developed in a way that initial URL's like example.com/en/ and others work fine when there is trailing slash at the end of it, and if we take off trailing slash manually, it adds itself so URL works fine with or without trailing slash. Problem comes only for en/authors/* category where if we add trailing slash at the URL end like example.com/en/authors/abc/ it shows 404 error. So, I was trying to remove trailing slash via nginx at the end of any URL starting from example.com/en/authors/*

Comment: Sounds like this should work.  Note that this is untested. >>> rewrite ^(\/example.com/\en\/authors.*)\/$ $1 permanent; <<< --- the >>> <<< are not part of the solution, and this is untested.  You may get by with not escaping the / >>> ^(example.com/en/authors.*)/$ $1 permanent; <<<

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for getting back, I tried today and this has worked for me `rewrite ^(\/\en\/authors.*)\/$ $1 permanent;` the only change I made was to remove domain name and it then worked. Please post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, you are most kind.  I have created such an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work.

Note that this is untested.

```
rewrite ^(\/example.com/\en\/authors.*)\/$ $1 permanent;
```

You may get by with not escaping the /, as in:

```
rewrite ^(example.com/en/authors.*)/$ $1 permanent;
```